# Sublime Text 2 always opens empty window

Tags: sublimetext2

I am opening a Sublime Text 2 project with the following command using gksudo in order to be able to edit some system files:

`gksudo /usr/bin/subl /home/orschiro/.sublime/system-administration.sublime-project`

However, what Sublime does is it opens the project in a window but additionally shows another empty window:

[image]

I already tried adding the following to the project and user settings but it does not resolve the problem:

```
"open_files_in_new_window": false,
"hot_exit": false
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can stop Sublime from opening that additional empty window?

Answer (score 7):

In your settings file, try:

```
"create_window_at_startup": false
```

Comment: Yes and if I start subl without the gksudo `/usr/bin/subl /home/orschiro/.sublime/system-administration.sublime-project`, then it is just opening one window. Any ideas why does gksudo does not respect the settings?

Comment: Thanks a lot did work perfectly for me. As my settings window was splitted, I just added it to the right one. did work perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

You can try `"create_window_at_startup": false`, but that might only apply to OSX. Another option is to try `"close_windows_when_empty": true`.

Is your `/usr/bin/subl` a link to `/path/to/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text`, or do you have a `-w` specified as well? The `-w` option is not needed, so that's another thing to look at.

Good luck!

Comment: `subl` directly links to `/usr/bin/subl`. I added both options to my settings but it still opens this additional window. I think it is somehow related to the `gksudo` prefix. Can it be that gksudo does not consider the settings although I have edited them whilst having subl opened via the gksudo command?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older issue and only for ST2 but none of these fixes worked for me on ST3. I was able to fix it by removing sublime text 2 and re creating my symlink with sublime text 3 (even though that is what it was linked to already). It seems it may have been confused by the multiple applications.